# Problem with stitching_detailed.cpp opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I use the code from the example
https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/dd8/samples_2cpp_2stitching_detailed_8cpp-example.html

I execute the program using that code with the command line

```
Project1.exe stitching_detailed D:\MEDIA\IMG_20190208_144719.jpg D:\MEDIA\IMG_20190208_144719.jpg —warp cylindrical
```

I get the answer

```
Finding features... 
Unknown 2D features type: 'surf'.
```

Please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: My guess would be, you have the `HAVE_OPENCV_XFEATURES2D` flag activated, thus `surf` is used per default (and you didn't provide a specific feature extractor in your command line call), but your actual library / libraries (e.g. `opencv_worldxxx.dll`) doesn't / don't have the `xfeatures2d/nonfree` features compiled into.

Comment: Try --features=orb or --features=akaze